# Remove auto line break in html email

Tags: php, gmail

I would like to know how can I remove the auto line break in email. I am using the phpmailer function:

```
$from = 'dass@gmail.com';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: admin@gmail.com \r\n";
$returnPath = "-r".$from;
mail($to, $subject, $msgbody, $headers, $returnPath)
```

Here is a running example: 
[jsfiddle.net/qwyh0551/](https://jsfiddle.net/qwyh0551/)

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qwyh0551/

Comment: line breaks in msgbody?

Comment: this is mail content

Comment: Never heard of auto line break before, check your code, it's possible there's a `&nbsp;` hidden somewhere (or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
<td>What ki
 nd
```

By this code:

```
<td>What kind
```

And your problem is gone. The french fries link does work in the fiddle, so I assume you already fixed that.